# How can you group custom post types in the admin sidebar?

Tags: custom-post-types

Is there an easy way to group custom post types on the admin sidebar menu?

The reason i ask is because i want to try to accomplish the following:

I've created a custom post type titled "Latest News" it's nothing more than a block area that will have a link that links out to another website so there are only two custom fields in this post type "URL" and "Headline Text".

However I will use this custom post type on 27 other different pages and this would not even be an issue if i could just use the same content on all of those 27 pages. Instead there needs to be custom news for each of those 27 pages.

Here's my noob approach:

I will create 27 different custom post types that have a unique description but ALL have the exact same custom fields which i'll have to create repeatedly as well for each of the 27 pages just so that i can link them to their specific custom post type and include that unique description within the specific page that the news will be relevant to.

I know it's a super bloated way to do things and WordPress probably has a better way to do this that requires knowing "if else" statements within custom functions. While i'm not afraid to try that i don't know very well how to do that but am willing to work it.

So as you can tell creating 27 custom post types just for this "Latest News" block area will make my Admin menu so long, hence the title of this question on how to group CPT's in the admin sidebar menu, but that's not really what i'm after.

Not to mention that if i can't find a better way to do this i'll end up doing the same thing for 10 other custom post types i need to make that will also go on 27 pages that are all using the same template but require unique content. That alone would make a sidebar admin menu with 297 custom post types and that's just insane.

Someone slap me and tell me what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

```
 <?php

    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'latest_news',
            'tax_query' => array(
                   'taxonomy' => 'news',
                   'field' => 'slug'
                   )
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>


      <?php the_field( 'url_latest_news' ); ?>


    <?php endwhile; else: ?>


    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why not one CPT and and a custom taxonomy to differentiate the content for the 27 different pages?

Comment: @s_ha_dum ok this is interesting to me i'll research how custom taxonomies work. I'm also wondering why, when a new Field Group is created, don't they have unique ID"s to them so that you can can call on that specific ID or set of ID's from any given page. When i research taxonomies in relation to Field Groups how do they associate? For example i'm using ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) plugin and i'll look to see if there wan an option to include a taxonomy but otherwise how would you go about creating the taxonomies for different pages that you would want to call a certain field group from?

Comment: does that make sense? Wait i just remember something about taxonomies when i created the Custom Post Type using the Custom Post Type UI plugin. I'll investigate that and see if that would help because it's still unclear to me how taxonomies work at the Field Group level because i'm thinking if taxonomies are only available at the custom post type level wouldn't i still have to create 27 custom post types each with their own taxonomy or am i missing the point of what Taxonomies are all about? Anyways off to research, thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Sorry, what does an ACF Field Group have to do with the admin menu on the left? I think you are missing the point though. Maybe I should just sketch out an answer...

Comment: The ACF Field Group Doesn't have really anything to do with the admin menu on the left. As i'm sure you know, this plugin is used to create the Field Groups for your Custom Post Types. The Custom Post Types on the other hand do obviously created a new admin menu item for whatever post type you created and it was this in particular i feared would happen due to my lack of understanding how content is dynamically generated for 27 pages that all will use the template (when i make it) but require their own unique set of content.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are doing, and I may not, I would not do this with multiple Custom Post types, much less 27 of them.

I would...

1. Create a single Custom Post Type for this "Latest News" data.
2. Create a Custom Taxonomy to sort the data. This taxonomy would have
   27 terms to correspond to, and serve instead of, the CPTs that you
   are thinking about making.
3. Create a theme template or templates to handle the data

To make this work, you would create a new post in your CPT and mark the appropriate term in your custom taxonomy. The template(s) you create in the theme would then display posts from the CPT according to a taxonomy argument-- that is display posts based on the term chosen.

Comment: i answered your other question before reading this answer. This is cool i'm going to mull it over in my head and work one example out and see how i do. Great stuff though, thank you.

Comment: ok i'm baby-stepping this to make every step concrete. I created the CPT for Latest News. I created a custom Taxonomy titled "Homepage News" to identify it's relevance. Then I added a Latest News and inside of that "post" there is now a widget on the sidebar of the CPT i created titled "Homepage News" with an input field and i'm not quite sure what to do with that, are those for tags?

Comment: Now regarding the template point. I will be creating a template titled "Single Neighborhood" that will also have this "Latest News" CPT in the same spot that i have it on the homepage. This new template will be used 27 times for different neighborhoods (hence the reason the news has to be unique to each hood).

Comment: Now when i create this template the "taxonomy argument" you refer to I assume is some kind of array? And if so would that mean that every page i create (because there will have to be 27 pages totaling all the hoods) using the template "Single Neighborhood" will have to have some kind of taxonomy identifier (which i haven't figured out how that works yet) in order for the argument to know which content to display for that neighborhood, is that how it works?

Comment: that is to say that the loop inside of this "Single Neighborhood" template will have to have an array with some parameter (i haven't figured out or know that exists yet) that would display the content based on the matching taxonomy of that particular page? Sorry for my long-windedness.

Comment: What you want is a `tax_query`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: I wish i understood but i still don't get it. I don't know where to enter custom taxonomies or how they work. I tried to enter a custom taxonomy within the Custom Post Type UI plugin but that just adds a sidebar widget/attribute to the actual custom post type edit area. For example in my new CPT title "Single Neighborhood" i can add a neighborhood when i do i have my custom fields that i enter information onto and on the sidebar it shows individual widgets each with just a single form field and every widget is titled with the taxonomy name i entered for the single neighborhood CPT.

Comment: So i'm still not sure if i should enter taxonomies through this plugin or do it some other manual way. Either way i'm more confused than ever about how to create identical content areas on repeated template pages but have it pull unique content. Also i'm not even sure if the best approach is to group various unique content areas into one CPT or create individual CPT's for each unique content area? But then i run into the same mind-numbing question which is how do i call on these unique content areas from within my template? It's so confusing but i don't want to give up i'm just disheartened.

Comment: i tried using the tax_query and used the taxonomy "news" that i created (see updated code above) but now not matter where i place this content template it just pulls up all of the latest news for all taxonomies. Is there a way to get more specific within the array? Thanks.

Comment: I've also updated the custom fields within the latest_news custom post type to only be a WYSIWYG instead of having a field for URL and Title name this took more advantage of what WP already has available therefore i didn't have to include a <ul> or <li> tag within the loop but rather just the_field() function.